# Convert a specific equation from polar to cartesian

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Convert the equations $r\cos(\theta)=−7\sin(2\theta)$ to Cartesian coordinates

I am aware that:

$$\begin{cases}
x=r\cos(\phi)\\
y=r\sin(\phi)
\end{cases},$$

where $r^2=x^2+y^2$.
However, I can't seem to find an approach to this and can not find any examples that are similar to approach it I am doing:

$$r=−7\sin(2\theta)\\
r=-7\frac{y}{r}\\
r^2=-7y \\
x^2+y^2=-7y\\
x^2 +y^2+7y=0.$$

and then here I get stuck since if i complete the square I don't get the right answer: 
 $$x^2+(y+7)^2=7^2$$ and $$x=0$$

Comment: How did you get rid of the $\cos\theta$ in the first line?

Comment: What did you do with $\cos\theta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the double angle identity:

$$r\cos\theta=-7\sin2\theta=-14\sin\theta\cos\theta$$

Now the cosines can cancel, leaving us with

$$r=-14\sin\theta$$

$$r^2=-14r\sin\theta$$

$$x^2+y^2=-14y$$

$$x^2+y^2+14y+49=7^2$$

> $$x^2+(y+7)^2=7^2$$

Comment: There is also the "degenerate" solution $\cos \theta = 0$.

Comment: It's not degenerate: the curve has two components, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

$$x=r\cos\theta=-14\cos\theta\sin\theta=-14\frac{r\cos\theta\cdot r\sin\theta}{r^2}=-14\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},$$
whence the equation:
$$x(x^2+y^2)=-14xy\iff x\bigl(x^2+y^2+14y\bigr)=0,$$
which is the equation of the *union* of the $y$-axis ($x=0$) and the circle centred on the $y$-axis at $(0,-7)$, with radius $7$ ($x^2+y^2+14y=0$).